# How to get all files in a specific branch in a GIT repository in VSTS through VSTS REST API?

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

How to get all files in a specific branch in a GIT repository in VSTS through VSTS REST API? 
Our project has multiple repositories and each repository may have multiple branches, like a branch for each user story and sometimes a branch for a separate feature.
The below endpoint lets me get all items from the Repository, but from which branch is this endpoint returning the list of files? How do I get the list of files from a specific branch, say for example from a branch named *Feature0001*

> GET
>   https://{accountName}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/items?api-version=4.1

Please advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation for this API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/git/items/list?view=vsts-rest-4.1) mentions a `versionDescriptor.version` query string parameter, documented as `Version string identifier (name of tag/branch, SHA1 of commit)`. This should work if you append `&versionDescriptor.version=Feature0001` to your URI.

If you don't supply this argument, I would expect the API to return the repository's default branch (eg. master).